# Embed Twitter timeline in al-folio website on github pages

Tags: javascript, ruby, content-security-policy

I am using the [`al-folio` template](https://github.com/alshedivat/al-folio) to build a personal website that I will host on github pages.
I would like to embed my Twitter timeline.

If I go to https://publish.twitter.com/, and input https://twitter.com/StackOverflow, it says I should paste the following code on my website:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/StackOverflow?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by StackOverflow</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

However, when I do that, I cannot see the timeline. Looking at the developer console, it says:

```
Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).
```

I tried adding

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;
    img-src * 'self' data: https: http:;
    script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *;
    style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

But:

1. I don't know if this is a good idea.
2. It does not work.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: HI, did you solve it? - I am looking for the same solution....

Answer (score 0):

There is a policy somewhere blocking the content. Adding another policy as you do in meta can only make it stricter, so that won't help.

There is likely a CSP on your page that you need to modify to allow the content you want to include. Check the console errors for exactly which sources and directives are needed.

If this is due to a twitter CSP there is nothing you can do about it.